# Why does AWS CLI rds describe-db-snapshots not include Aurora snapshots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I can see 77 "System" snapshots in us-east-1 on the website / AWS Console. When I run the following:

```sh
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --region us-east-1 --include-shared --include-public --no-paginate --output text
```

... I get 35. I tried this in AWS CloudShell as well as locally with the access/secret from https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/security_credentials so this should be running with maximum (my) privileges.

I *think* it's excluding Aurora snapshots because the only `engine` value I see is `postgres` and not `aurora-postgresql`. I am going crazy trying to figure out why I can't see everything with the CLI ... any thoughts, pointers, RTFM's?

---

**UPDATE**: I added `--filters "Name=engine,Values=aurora-postgresql"` and sure enough the output is blank whereas `--filters "Name=engine,Values=postgres"` shows the 30+ entries for non-Aurora. So why are Aurora snapshots being excluded?

Comment: I think Aurora uses [`describe-db-cluster-snapshots`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-cluster-snapshots.html).

Comment: <<@JohnRotenstein is right, you need to use describe-db-cluster-snapshots as this action only applies to aurora db cluster so you might needs to combine your aurora and rds commands together to combine their output

Answer (score 3):

(Thanks to @JohnRotenstein for the answer in a comment to my question.)

There is a separate command called [describe-db-cluster-snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-cluster-snapshots.html) that operates very similarly and outputs results for clusters, obviously, like Aurora. The only way to get the full list as seen in the Console is to combine this output with `describe-db-snapshots`.